# libgdx - Crossfading two sprites

Tags: libgdx

I have two sprites and I want to fade from one into the other like:

```
Sprite sprite1, sprite2;
float alpha = 1;
...

public void render(float delta) {
   alpha -= 0.01f;
   if (alpha<0) alpha = 0;

   sprite1.setAlpha(alpha);
   sprite2.setAlpha(1-alpha);
   sprite1.draw(batch);
   sprite2.draw(batch);
}
```

But when I do this the blending is not right, the combined image becomes almost completely transparent around where alpha is 0.5. I've made a video of the problem here: http://vimeo.com/100472883 - sprite1 is the sharp cloud image, sprite2 is the blurred cloud image and I'm fading from one to the other and back.

If I use `batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_CONSTANT_ALPHA);` before drawing sprites, the alpha of the images looks good, but it messes up the colors of both sprites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think they're going "almost completely" transparent but rather just partially transparent. If you have two 50% transparent objects in front of each other, you can still see through the pair of them. If you were doing a full-screen crossfade, the way you would correctly do it is draw one of the two sprites at 100% alpha behind the other sprite, and only modify the alpha of the sprite in front. However, it is not so easy when both sprites have an alpha channel.

One way would be with multi-texturing, which is not really how SpriteBatch is designed. If you did multi-texturing with SpriteBatch, you would need to make sure both sprites were aligned to the same TextureRegion of their respective Textures, or you could put them in the same texture and use a known offset in your shader to separate them. Then you could use a custom shader to blend the two sprites in the shader before drawing them.

If your sprites are going to remain monochrome, this becomes much easier. You can just combine the two sprites into one sprite by putting one sprite''s color and alpha in the R and G channels of the image and the other sprite's color and alpha in the B and A channels. Then use a custom shader with a fragment shader like this:

```
String fragmentShader = "#ifdef GL_ES\n" //
            + "#define LOWP lowp\n" //
            + "precision mediump float;\n" //
            + "#else\n" //
            + "#define LOWP \n" //
            + "#endif\n" //
            + "varying LOWP vec4 v_color;\n" //
            + "varying vec2 v_texCoords;\n" //
            + "uniform sampler2D u_texture;\n" //
            + "uniform float u_crossfade;\n" //
            + "void main()\n"//
            + "{\n" //
            + "  vec4 texture = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);\n" //
            + "  float sprite1Alpha = (1 - u_crossfade) * texture.g * v_color.a;\n" //
            + "  float sprite2Alpha = u_crossfade * texture.a * v_color.a;\n" //
            + "  gl_FragColor = v_color * vec4(vec3(sprite1Alpha*texture.r + sprite2Alpha*texture.b), sprite1Alpha + sprite2Alpha);\n" //
        + "}";
```

This should be drawn with blendfunc GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA since it pre-multiplies the alpha. And you need to call `customShader.setUniformf("u_crossfade", crossfadeBlendValue);` in between `spriteBatch.begin()` and `end()`. Which means you can only batch one sprite at a time if you need different crossfades per sprite.

You could get around this if you aren't planning to color tint your sprites, by using the R component of the sprite's tint to represent the blend value. Then the shader would become

```
String fragmentShader = "#ifdef GL_ES\n" //
            + "#define LOWP lowp\n" //
            + "precision mediump float;\n" //
            + "#else\n" //
            + "#define LOWP \n" //
            + "#endif\n" //
            + "varying LOWP vec4 v_color;\n" //
            + "varying vec2 v_texCoords;\n" //
            + "uniform sampler2D u_texture;\n" //
            + "void main()\n"//
            + "{\n" //
            + "  vec4 texture = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);\n" //
            + "  float sprite1Alpha = (1 - v_color.r) * texture.g * v_color.a;\n" //
            + "  float sprite2Alpha = v_color.r * texture.a * v_color.a;\n" //
            + "  gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(sprite1Alpha*texture.r + sprite2Alpha*texture.b), sprite1Alpha + sprite2Alpha);\n" //
        + "}";
```

Comment: I lost you after the first paragraph. I don't even know what a shader is... I wanted to fade one sprite into the other, but it's just not worth the effort if it's that complicated.